# Doctrine DQL, same result for 2 different query

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, doctrine-query

I have a problem with Cache of Dql query, I have this 6 lines:

```
$dql = "SELECT d, c FROM \Cms\Day d LEFT JOIN d.contents c WITH c INSTANCE OF Cms\Message ORDER BY d.num ASC";
$query = $this->_em->createQuery($dql);
$result1 = $query->getResult();

$dql = "SELECT d, c FROM \Cms\Day d LEFT JOIN d.contents c WITH c INSTANCE OF Cms\Article ORDER BY d.num ASC";
$query = $this->_em->createQuery($dql);
$result2 = $query->getResult();
```

I Have try that (before $query->getResult()) :

```
$query->useQueryCache(false);
$query->setQueryCacheLifetime(0);
$query->useResultCache(false);
$query->setQueryCacheDriver(null);
```

But I always have same results in $result1 and $result2 => there are equals and contain the results of the first query.

Some one can say me how solve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have just find that Cms\Days stay in the EntityManager ( _em ) for the 2 querys  so between the 2 getResult we can add :

```
$this->_em->clear();
```

or make a foreach on the result to detach the element :

```
foreach($result1 as $element) {
    $this->_em->detach($element);
}
```

Thanks Doctrine Lazy Loading ... :'(